# repeated measures survival analysis

Tags: repeated-measures, survival, kaplan-meier

I have various samples on which three survival time variates have been collected. How can I compare the difference of such variates taking into account within subject correlation (possibly in R)?

Comment: Would this be something like time to first, second and third infection/time to failure of three different parts of a machine/time to different disease stages? How are the measures related? Are they strictly ordered?

Comment: They represent measurements time of a quantity on the same sample by three different devices. In theory they do not influence each other ...

Answer (score 4):

If this is a simple subject correlation (i.e. like random intercepts in a mixed effects model), one can use a frailty model. An R-package to do this is "frailtypack".

If you wanted to fit more complex random effects, you can use the R-package "coxme" for fitting a Cox-PH model with general random effects.